# how to change programatically a date in a form library item?

Tags: client-object-model

I'm trying to change a date field in a form included in a form library (from a .net desktop app with sharepoint client runtime) but when I change it and open the form it crashes and says that is an error in the format of the xml

this is my code:

```
 nodes = xd.GetElementsByTagName("my:EntryDate");
                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                    {
                         //node.InnerText =  registro.Entry_Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ;
                        // node.InnerText = registro.Entry_Date.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM");
                         //node.InnerText = registro.Entry_Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                      //  node.InnerText =  registro.Entry_Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") ;
                         //node.InnerText = registro.Entry_Date.ToString("yyyy/dd/MM");
                       //  node.InnerText = registro.Entry_Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                    }
```

I have tested with different formats but when I try to open the form it crashes.